# Registration in React App only for users with certain email ending

Tags: reactjs

I would like to allow registration in my react app only for user with email that have a certain ending. For example only users with @tm.com at the end. Is this possible without making manually a "white list" which has to be updated all the time? 
My app is connected to firebase.

```
 import firebase from '../configureFirebase'
import * as types from '../constants/ActionTypes'
import {actionStart, actionFailed, actionSuccess} from './utils/template'

export const register = (email, password) => {
  return function(dispatch) {
    dispatch(actionStart(types.REGISTER))
    const promise = firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    promise.then((user) => {
      dispatch(actionSuccess(types.REGISTER, {user: user}))
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      let errorMessage

      switch (error.code) {
        case 'auth/weak-password':
          errorMessage = 'Passwort zu schwach'
          break
        default:
          errorMessage = error.message
      }
      dispatch(actionFailed(types.REGISTER, errorMessage))
    })
    //return promise so github.com/arnaudbenard/redux-mock-store works
    return promise
  }
}
```

Comment: `if (email.endsWith('@tm.com') { dispatch(actionFailed(bla)); }`

Answer (score 1):

You should consider to do it into Firebase instead of the front part of your application. There is rules for that into firebase that allows you to restrict the access to specific users. Here is a small example for the rules with `@tm.com` domain.

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    "restrictedUsers": {
      "$uid": {
        ".write": "auth.token.email_verified == true && auth.token.email.matches(/.*@tm.com$/)"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

They provide an example into the auth.token section [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database/)

You will then avoid having a list into the front part of your application.
Here are some benefits:

- Don't rebuild
- Don't expose the domains to the users
- Safer
- You can update it directly into firebase